# One Request to the Multiple Nginx Host with Args

Tags: http, nginx, lua, request, microservices

I've a little problem for request routing with Nginx for backend services .In my scenario I've a frontend service and another logging service for log the 404 requests with different request type .

---> serviceFrontend/product/productName ----> if 404 ----> serviceLogger?productId=productName

How I can create new request and send request at same time of serviceFrontend service triggered .

Please help me !

---

SOLVE OF THE PROBLEM

I've handled my problem with post_action annotation with nginx .

Resource :

https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,275992,275992

Answer (score 1):

You should have a custom error location for 404 error and pass request through proxy to your upstream. Also you need rewrite module to set `ProductName` at query string. Something like bellow:

```
location /serviceFrontend/product {
    error_page 404 = @log404;
}

location @log404 {
    rewrite ^/serviceFrontend/product/(.*)$ /serviceLogger?productId=$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://logger.example.com;
}
```